# keep button in div positioned along with parent div

Tags: css

I have the following:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KXYLrq

```
<header>
   <input type="text" id="textfield" placeholder="Get it done!" autofocus>
   <button id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</header>
```

with css that is too long to list. I'd like to focus on the `@media query`. Due to larger screen sizes i need to limit the width of the input bar. If i set a max-width, or fixed width the button will move along with the screen size and continually move to the right.

How do i fix the button in one position past a certain screen size ? (In codepen, if you take out the media query it works just fine, presumably because i set the width to 100%)

Comment: So, to keep the plus in the input?

Comment: @Gezzasa correct. to the very right border of it

Comment: Cool, My answer will fix that for you then :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this also in media query

```
header button{
    right: auto;
    left: 695px
}
```

It will help you to align the button with the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I placed a Container over your input and button, assuming you'll have other elements in the header later.

I then set the section as `display: inline-block` to make it take the width of the content and also made it `position: relative` for the child absolute elements. So that those elements will take the section as a starting point and not the header.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGRooL

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap input and button in one parent div and set position relative in it and add width in it.

```css
header {
  background: #25b99a;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.15);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 15px 25px 0 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}
header input {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 245, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px 25px 25px 5px;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-right: 65px;
  outline: none;
  text-indent: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
.search-box {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.search-box button {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .search-box {
   max-width: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" id="textfield" placeholder="Get it done!" autofocus>
    <button id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  </div>
</header>
```

Updated Codepen [Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boJyPg)